# Select all rows from a table where no columns are empty

Tags: mysql

[image]

When I use this query:

```
SELECT * from table
```

empty results are displayed as well.

When I use:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE tablet<>''
```

I get the result I want to achieve, but **only** for `tablet`. I would like to achieve this for the whole table.

Something like:

```
SELECT * from table //that is not empty
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you would like every column to not be empty?

Comment: perhaps `WHERE tablet<>'' and handy <> '' and pc <>'' and notebook <> ''`

Comment: `WHERE col1 <>'' OR col2<>''` and so on

Comment: Is it stored as an empty string or null?

Comment: the empty ones are stored as empty strings

Comment: That's all I need to know, gave you an answer and I edited with SQL Fiddle if you didn't see the edit.

Comment: I've made some final edits... im a SQL SERVER guy, hopefully all that is legal in MYSQL

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a single list with 2 columns:

```
SELECT `Handy` AS Category,
T.Handy AS Description
FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.Handy <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT `PC` AS Category,
T.PC AS Description
FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.PC <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT `Notebook` AS Category,
T.Notebook AS Description
FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.Notebook <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT `Tablet` AS Category,
T.Tablet AS Description
FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.Tablet <> ''
ORDER BY Category
```

Comment: I don't think that's what they're looking for. OP said `SELECT *` gave them what they want, but they had a hard time writing it to include that requirement for every column.

Comment: i don't understand how the results will ever be right.. unless they want a row ONLY when all 4 columns have a value.

Comment: That's how the question reads to me, but reading OP's comment on Robbert's answer you might be right.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, even if it doesn't go on to match the format OP wants. I would like to suggest two edits: You're missing your `FROM` statements, and `DESC` is reserved so I changed it to 'Description'. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fde0/5). It has a bunch of junk stuff that I input to test my answer though.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I copied it into fiddle and was racking my brains trying to find your syntax error.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I don't know, I might be doing something wrong, but I'm now getting 39 results for every column. It sounds somewhat ridiculous lol

Comment: are they different values?  you should get 2 columns, the first is the Device type and the Description column should be the value of the Handy/Notebook/Tablet/PC....  post your results...  this should work for you.

Comment: and FYI the result should be 39 rows, with 2 columns.. if that is what you are getting then that is correct.

Comment: I see only one problem with this query.  In MySQL fields are quoted with a backtick not a single quote. The query you presented would cause the string "Handy" to appear instead of the value of the handy field.

Comment: Actually, @Robbert, you *dont* want backticks here, because you're not specifying the field handy, you're giving the cell value 'Handy'. If you use backticks, you'll get the actual value twice. Look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fde0/6) for example.

Comment: I guess I it depends on if OP wants the word Handy or the value of the Handy field.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use an `and` statement for each field

```
SELECT * from table WHERE tablet<>'' AND handy<>'' AND pc<>''
```

(Sorry, my work blocks imgr.com so I can't see your screenshot, and don't know all the columns in your table).

Comment: When I do that it does not return all results for each column. For example, for 'handy' only 5 results are shown.

Comment: @sehetmich isn't that what you want? That's how your question reads to me. If it's not, you should update your question with expected results.

Comment: @McAdam331: No. The problem is that currently there are shown 12 results per column, but some columns don't have all 12 results filled with a string. Like `tablet`, for example, it contains only 5. Now what I would like to achieve is to display the real amount of results for each column. (10 for handy, 5 for tablet...), do you know what I mean?

Comment: my answer solves that.. that's how I interpreted your question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna hop on #team @TMcKeown on this one, he nailed it. You'll have to use that format, because there's no way to list them in individual columns, as I said in the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bunch of `!= ''` conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  handy != '' AND
       pc != '' AND
       notebook != '' AND
       tablet != ''
```

Comment: same result like `Select * from table`. Probably because `not null` is not the same as `not empty`, right?

Comment: Arg, in MySQL it is - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A neat query using only a where clause would be to use the [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function, and make sure that the smallest value is not empty, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE LEAST(handy, pc, notebook, tablet) <> '';
```

**EDIT**

Works in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fde0/1).

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this has the same effect like `SELECT * from table WHERE tablet<>'' AND handy<>'' AND pc<>''`... this way there are only shown 5 results per column, while 'handy', for example, contains 10.

Comment: So what are you actually looking for? Handy contains ten, and pc contains 12, I can't return 12 rows without two of them having an empty column. Do you see the problem?

Comment: I see what you're referring to. The thing is that I'm echoing every one of these columns in form of `<a>` tags, which come with a distinct style that even appears when there is no text at all between the tags. I suppose there is no way to only display 5 rows for tablet, 10 for handy,... ?

Comment: @sehetmich no, because your entire result set will be as long as the column with the most entries. Although T Mck has a really good alternative solution to this.